# handleSubmit in react-hook-form not allowing state changes

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-hook-form

Using **react-testing-library** I am doing a very simple test : just rendering a component and clicking on a button.

```
it('tests a button click', async () => {

    render(<Test/>)

    await screen.findAllByRole('heading')

    let buttons = await screen.findAllByRole("button");
    fireEvent.click(buttons[0]);
});
```

My component "Test" is very simple, containing just a heading and form with a button.

The form uses **react-hook-form**, and I would like to *react* to the submitting of the form. I would like to change the value of my "foobar" object.

However in the following code the "console.info" will never be called.

```
export default function Test() {

    const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const [foobar, setFoobar] = React.useState<string>("foo");

    if (foobar) {
        console.info("this will never get called if onSubmit is called from handleSubmit")
    }

    const onSubmit = () => {
        setFoobar("bar")
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <button type={"submit"}>Hi</button>
            </form>
        </>
    );
}
```

I do not understand this behaviour, because if I just have a normal button like in the code below, the "console.info" WILL be called.

```
export default function Test() {

    const { handleSubmit } = useForm();

    const [foobar, setFoobar] = React.useState<string>("foo");

    if (foobar) {
        console.info("this will never get called if onSubmit is called from handleSubmit")
    }

    const onSubmit = () => {
        setFoobar("bar")
    }
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Test</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            </form>
            <button onClick={()=>onSubmit()}>Hi</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Strangely, this seems to only happen when I use "react testing library".

If I use both these examples in my actual application then *BOTH* "console.info" will be called.

So, at this stage I am not sure if the problem lies with **react-hook-form** or with **react-testing-library**.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap the `fireEvent` call inside an `act(...)` it should work:

```
it('tests a button click', async () => {

  render(<Test/>)

  await screen.findAllByRole('heading');

  let buttons = await screen.findAllByRole('button');

  await act(async () => {
    fireEvent.click(buttons[0]);
  });

});
```

Comment: wow that works. I dont understand ... all i can take away from this is that "act" : "This makes your test run closer to how React works in the browser"